# Pointers vs Values

Tags: go

I'm a bit wondering why the following code does work:

```
var serverStartedTime time.Time // Holds the time since the server is started.

type ServerInformation struct {
    Uptime ServerUptimeInformation `json:"uptime"`
}

type ServerUptimeInformation struct {
    Hours       int64 `json:"hours"`
    Minutes     int64 `json:"minutes"`
    Seconds     int64 `json:"seconds"`
    NanoSeconds int64 `json:"nanoSeconds"`
}

func main() {
    serverStartedTime = time.Now()

    http.HandleFunc("/api/v1/health", getHealthHandler)

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil))
}

func handler(writer http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(writer, "URL.Path = %q\n", request.URL.Path)
}


func getHealthHandler(writer http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    serverUptime := time.Now().Sub(serverStartedTime)

    hours := int64(serverUptime.Hours())
    minutes := int64(serverUptime.Minutes()) - (hours * 60)
    seconds := int64(serverUptime.Seconds()) - (hours * 60) - (minutes * 60)
    nanoSeconds := int64(serverUptime.Nanoseconds()) - (hours * 60) - (minutes * 60) - (seconds * 1000000000)

    serverInformation := ServerInformation{
        ServerUptimeInformation{
            hours, minutes, seconds, nanoSeconds,
        },
    }

    returnJSON(writer, serverInformation)
}

func returnJSON(writer http.ResponseWriter, data ...interface{}) {
    dataJSON, marshalError := json.Marshal(data)

    if marshalError != nil {
        writer.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
    } else {
        writer.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
        writer.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        writer.Write(dataJSON)
    }
}
```

By default Go copies parameters that are provided to methods.
So, the HTTP handler for '/api/v1/health' does take a writer and we pass it to the `returnJSON` method.

So, this method does receives a copy on which it writes.

How does it come that in my browser, I do see the response?
I didn't expected that since the writer is being copied.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Your title mentions pointers and values. Your body has a large block of code, and then your question is "Why do I see a response?" Please narrow your question down _drastically_, and include only relevant code.  What is your specific question about pointers and values?

Comment: The question here is why I do see a value since the writer is copied over to a new method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You think that [ResponseWriter](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ResponseWriter) is a struct, but it is an interface.

Every time you send `writer http.ResponseWriter` into your method you send pointer to struct that implements that interface.

Execute this line to see actual type:

```
fmt.Printf("%T\n", writer)
```

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for the clarification.